# Unity unable to login (can login with xubuntu)

Tags: unity, gnome, xubuntu, login, lightdm

Any and all help would be appreciated...

Ok so. My laptop is Ubuntu 14.04, and the other day I restarted it and then was no longer able to login. So what happens? I attempt to login (lightdm) and then it goes to wallpaper only (not the user wallpaper), waits a while then goes back to the login screen.

So why do I need your help - Isn't there lots of threads talking about this already?
Yes there is however I can not find any which solve it for me.

This is what I have tried:

- Removed .Xauthority
- 777 pem .Xauthority
- Reinstall gnome-session, ubuntu-desktop, unity
- Update everything
- Reconfigure lightdm
- Reinstall Xorg
- I may have done more. But will update as appropriate.

I am able to login with both terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and also with xubuntu-desktop (but not gnome-shell!)

Upon trying to view some crash logs (/usr/crash/_usr_gnome_session..._) It is due to signal 11?

Some additional information. I am unable to use gdm as my screen goes black and nothing happens. I am also unable to log into the guest account. Also I do not have enough linux knowledge to see all the packages which changed which might have affected this.

Comment: For me (OP) this was fixed via the duplicate post.